# Keyboard locale indicator shows en-US even though I set it to be pt-BT

Tags: 13.10, indicator

I am having an issue with my keyboard. My keyboard is pt-BR layout, and I set on the configurations to be pt-BR by default. But when I login on my system, it is set on en-US, but the applet shows pt-BR. So I have to click the applet and click pt-BR to it be set. I have no other language installed on my system, just pt-BR. What could it be? Thank you.

Ps. This started happening a little time ago. When I installed Saucy everything was going ok, but from a week to now this issue appeared.